# Angular 12 - two-way binding gives error: The property and event halves of the two-way binding 'prop_name' are not bound to the same target

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, two-way-binding

Migrated from Angular 11 to Angular 12 and this issue pops out:

"**Error:** The property and event halves of the two-way binding 'value' are not bound to the same target."

Parent Page Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child [(value)]="counterValue"></app-child>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class ParentComponent {
  counterValue = 0;
}
```

Child Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    {{ value }}
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() value = 0;
  @Output() incrementValue = new EventEmitter<number>();

  increase(): void {
    this.value++;
    this.incrementValue.emit(this.value);
  }
}
```

Here es a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webcontainer-template-dekvlh?file=README.md) code for you to test it your self:

Is this a bug?
or am I missing something?

Comment: the emitter should be called `valueChange`  (property+Change) see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works). Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webcontainer-template-c3awt5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)

Comment: I had this problem with a third party js library and changed "strictTemplates": false in tsconfig. Clearly this is not a fix per se, but it got me going.

Answer (score 2):

The Output Decorator should be `valueChange` instead of `incrementValue`.

According to Angular documentation for Two-way binding:

- the inputDecorator `@Input` propertyName
- the OutputDecorator `@Output` propertyNameChange

In your code you used `@Input` as value, so `@Output` should be `valueChange`.

Answer (score 1):

I just used a work-around to continue developing while this issue gets solved.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child [value]="counterValue" (incrementValue)="onChange($event)"></app-child>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class ParentComponent {
  counterValue = 0;
  onChange(n:number) {
    this.counterValue = n;
  }
}
```